# Related questions not showing up when opening a question on main

Tags: bug, related-questions

Whenever I open a question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), there is no "Related questions" section in the sidebar.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, I couldn't find it by myself. Closing as dupe.